# Manipulating integral values in java without Integer casting?

Tags: java

Consider the following

```
public byte GetAByte()
{
    return (byte)(_globalByte % 13);
}
```

Note that the following will not work and throws an error.

```
    return (_globalByte % (byte)13);
```

Here the mod operator is returning an integer, which needs to be casted back to a byte for the return statement to work. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I am guessing that the _globalByte is casted to an integer before the modulus is calculated. This in total, means 2 casting operations.

So my question is why do the basic operators have to return an integer every time? Is this is a quirk specific to java, or is there some importance for doing it this way?

Comment: you don't need to caste if 13 was byte

Comment: @JigarJoshi tried casting 13 to byte and did not work. Amended my question to include that.

Comment: http://ideone.com/dDVXtw

Comment: @JigarJoshi println will take an integer so, that does not prove anything unless it only took a byte, like my return statement does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So my question is why do the basic operators have to return an integer every time?  Is this is a quirk specific to java, or is there some importance for doing it this way?

The reason it happens is that the Java integral arithmetic operators are defined as `int op int -> int` (or `long op long -> long`).

Why they defined it that way?  I'm not sure, but I can think of three possible explanations:

- Efficient implementation across a range of native instruction sets / architectures.
- Consistency with other languages like C and C++.  (I'm not an expert on the standards for these languages, but I found the place in the C99 language spec which says this ... section 6.3.1.1 para 2.)
- Mathematical consistency.

IMO, the latter is probably the most significant.

Suppose that there was an overload for `+` with signature `byte op byte -> byte`.  Now we have a situation where `+` is no longer associative.  Assume that we have `byte b1, b2; int i;` then

- `(b1 + b2) + i` does the first `+` using the `byte` operator, and then the second `+` using the `int` operator.
- `b1 + (b2 + i)` does the second `+` using the `int` operator, and then the first `+` using the `int` operator.

Note that if bytewise `b1 + b2` overflows, the two different ways of evaluating the compound expression will give *different answers*.

But automatically widening the operands to `int` and doing the operations as `int op int -> int` avoids this.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is called 'implicit widening conversion'.

When an operation is done on two types then the lower type is implicitly converted to the upper type. Hence your `_globalByte` is converted to int using implicit conversion when you try to to operate it with `int` value 13 using `modulus` operator.

Comment: Are you sure?  return (_globalByte % (byte)13); does not work either.

Comment: @BlazArt   return (byte)(_globalByte % 13); will work but maybe in a wrong way. Because as we know the result of _globalByte % 13 is an int value. So downcasting int to byte may result in loss of information and undesired value.

Comment: Can you clarify? That comment does not make sense and does not answer question.

Comment: There's more to it than stated here. Any operation on byte, char, or short will return an int, even if there aren't any other ints in the expression. Any operation on float will return a double. See the JLS.